# SpringBoot CouchbaseTemplate: findbyId is working But findByQuery not

Tags: spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase, couchbase-java-api, spring-boot-configuration

Can anyone help me to undersand:

In Spring Data Couchbase: **spring-data-couchbase : 4.3.0**
Couchbase Version: **6.6.2**

By using couchbasetemplate

- findById(Entity.class).one(id) is working fine, I am able to fetch
  data
- findByQuery(Entity.class).all() returning empty array
- findByQuery(Entity.class).count() returning 0

Comment: If you include a little information about your platform and the version of CB you are using, you'll probably get a better answer...

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike information updated

Answer (score 0):

This is described in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/issues/1321 which is fixed in today's release of 4.3.2.

If the problem persists, please open a new issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/issues/new